# Substitute for useRouteMatch to get Params

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

i'm doing a refactoring in this code and i cant find a good replace for this part, because of the react-router-dom v6 that doesnt have the useRouteMatch, because i need to get the params that are in the url:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouteMatch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FiChevronLeft, FiChevronRight } from 'react-icons/fi';
import api from '../../services/api';

import { Header, RepositoryInfo, Issues } from './styles';
import logoImg from '../../assets/logo.svg';

interface RepositoryParams {
  repository: string;
}

interface Repository {
  full_name: string;
  description: string;
  stargazers_count: number;
  forks_count: number;
  open_issues_count: number;
  owner: {
    login: string;
    avatar_url: string;
  };
}

interface Issue {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  html_url: string;
  user: {
    login: string;
  };
}

const Repository: React.FC = () => {
  const [repository, setRepository] = useState<Repository | null>(null);
  const [issues, setIssues] = useState<Issue[]>([]);

  const { params } = useRouteMatch<RepositoryParams>();

  useEffect(() => {
    api.get(`repos/${params.repository}`).then((response) => {
      setRepository(response.data);
    });

    api.get(`repos/${params.repository}/issues`).then((response) => {
      setIssues(response.data);
    });
  }, [params.repository]);
```

So thats my code, i need to change this 'const { params } = useRouteMatch();'

Comment: Have you tried the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) hook? It exists for exactly this purpose.

Comment: but then this happen interface RepositoryParams
Type 'RepositoryParams' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | Record<string, string | undefined>'.
  Type 'RepositoryParams' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string | undefined>'.
    Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'RepositoryParams'.ts(2344)

Answer (score 0):

Declare `RepositoryParams` as a type instead of an interface and use the `useParams` hook.

Example:

```
type RepositoryParams = {
  repository: string;
}

...

const params = useParams<RepositoryParams>();

...

params.repository
```

[image: Edit substitute-for-useroutematch-to-get-params]